# Cuckoo with pfSense

Tags: networking, malware

I am trying to set up Cuckoo with pfSense, and it is either not getting the information from the Cuckoo server, or it is not correctly sending the info back to the result server. I am using a LAN segment and Bridged network connections on VMware, both have an ip of 192.168.5.xxx. They can ping each other, but when run, Cuckoo just displays the python windows counting every second, and then eventually crashes with a timeout error. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: You have already posted on the Cuckoo forums, and that's the best place. http://community.cuckoosandbox.org/